# How to fade whole html body content except one hovered using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assume that my html is like below:

```
<div id="content">
   <div class="container">
       <div class="not-to-be-fade">
       </div>   
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is my js code :

```
$('.not-to-be-fade').hover(function(){
    $('#content).not('.not-to-be-fade').fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
})
```

By this, all html body fade and div with class `not-to-be-fade` fade too, but I want div with class `not-to-be-fade` to not fade.

Comment: when your div with class `container` fades, all the content inside gets faded. `not-to-be-faded` is inside `container`

Comment: @asHK no way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the jquery [not-selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/);
`$(":not(.className)")`

Instead of fading the actual `.container`, **fade the content of the `.container`**.

Try the snippet below.

```js
$('.not-to-be-fade').hover(function() {
  $('.container div:not(.not-to-be-fade)').fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
}, function() {
  $('.container div:not(.not-to-be-fade)').fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
```

```css
.not-to-be-fade {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.container div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div class="not-to-be-fade">
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this looks good because you haven't set backgound color to the container or the content divs.

Comment: @jerdine you are fading div inside `container`, where the OP ask about fading div inside `content`

Comment: hi @asHK yes. I'm suggesting that instead of fading the whole `.container`, the OP could fade the content inside `.container`.

Answer (score 0):

this code doesn't work if the targeted element has position absolute or fixed yet. I will complete it when I have time.

What happen here is that I create 1 wrapper div and 4 additional div these 4 divs have background color `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)` and with some calculation this is the result [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nucdo1tw/2/)

```js
$('.not-to-be-fade').mouseenter(function(){
    var width = this.offsetWidth;
    var height = this.offsetHeight;
    
    var maj = document.createElement('div');
    
    var top = $(this).offset().top;
    var left = $(this).offset().left;
    var bottom = document.documentElement.clientHeight - (top + this.offsetHeight);
    var right = document.documentElement.clientWidth - (left + this.offsetWidth);
    
    for(let i=0; i<4; i++){
       var div = document.createElement('div');
       div.id = "absolute-"+i;
       maj.append(div);
       if(i==0){
         div.style.height = top+"px";
       }
       if(i==1){
         div.style.height = bottom+"px";
       }
       if(i==2){
         div.style.width = left+"px";
         div.style.height = this.offsetHeight+"px";
         div.style.top = top+"px";
       }
       if(i==3){
         div.style.width = right+"px";
         div.style.height = this.offsetHeight+"px";
         div.style.top = top+"px";
       }
    }
    $(maj).insertAfter($(this))
    maj.append(this);

    this.style.width = width+"px";
    this.style.height = height+"px";
});

$('.not-to-be-fade').mouseleave(function(){
    $( this.parentElement ).replaceWith( this );
    $(this).removeAttr("style");
});
```

```css
#content {
  background: #ffccaa;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.container {
  background: #ee9900;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@keyframes fade{
  0%{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  100%{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
}
.not-to-be-fade {
  background: #202020;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
}
.fade{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.long{
  width: 200px;
}

/*Inmportant styling */
#absolute-0{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200vw;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  animation: fade 0.5s linear;
}
#absolute-1{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200vw;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  animation: fade 0.5s linear;
}
#absolute-2{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  animation: fade 0.5s linear;
}
#absolute-3{
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  animation: fade 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
   <div class="container">
       <div class="fade long">
       </div>
       <div class="fade">
       </div>
       <div class="fade">
       </div>
       <div class="not-to-be-fade">
       Hover Here
       </div>
       <div class="fade">
       </div>
       <div class="fade">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ArashShiri have you checked this answer? What do you think?

Comment: It is working properly here, but in my case with lot's of html it is hard to impelement, by the way I got the point, TNX